# Credential from Firebase EmailAuthProvider not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I use firebase with react then need to convert anonymous account to permanent. I have follow firebase [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth) but when I try look like cannot use this function they have error message as undefined

in code

`let credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, pass)`

error message

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'credential' of undefined`

Someone please help me to fix a problem

ps. in my package

`"firebase": "^4.5.0"`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Got it and so sorry this is my first question thank for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

First check whether you are anonymously signed in or not.Below code will be helful to do so.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
if (user) {
   // User is signed in.
   var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
   var uid = user.uid;
// ...
} else {
    // User is signed out.
    // ...
}
 // ...
});
```

If you get some defined values then use *EmailAuthProvider* to get credentials.

```
var credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
```

Comment: Yes I still signIn and get anonymous data but when I use EmailAuthProvider credential they cannot find this function